# A Triangle of Squares

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Let $T(n) = 1 + 2 + 3 + \text{...} + n$ be the $n$th triangular number.

For which $n>1$, if any, is it possible to split the first $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ positive integers into $n$ sets, all of different sizes, and each of them with elements adding to a perfect square?

What if the squares must all be different?

Comment: n = 1 trivially solves both problems. I win.

Comment: @Bubbler You are right. I shall edit accordingly to disregard that trivial case.Sorry!

Answer (score 9):

Other than n = 1, it is easy to see that too small n's do not have such sets:

> n = 2: sum is 6, which does not have two-squares decomposition.
>
> n = 3: sum is 21, whose only three-squares decomposition is 16 + 4 + 1, but it is impossible because 6 + 5 + 4 < 16, or alternatively, 1 + 2 + 3 > 1 + 4.
>
> n = 4: sum is 55, which has only three distinct four-squares decomposition (25 + 25 + 4 + 1), (36 + 9 + 9 + 1), (49 + 4 + 1 + 1), none of which can solve the problem due to a similar argument.

The first n that has a solution in both parts is

> **n = 5**

which can be solved as follows:

> ```
> 1 = 1
> 9 = 3 + 6
> 25 = 2 + 10 + 13
> 36 = 4 + 5 + 12 + 15
> 49 = 7 + 8 + 9 + 11 + 14
> ```

Given this, I conjecture that

> all numbers n >= 5 permit such set partitions (even with the restriction of distinct squares), with at most a small finite number of exceptions

because

> 1) It is known that every positive integer has one or more four-square decompositions, and n-square decompositions (with n >= 5) will give more and more freedom in the choice of square numbers in the decomposition.
>
> 2) Sum of first T(n) numbers is quartic in n, which grows asymptotically faster than the sum of first n squares (which is cubic in n), supporting 1) further.
>
> 3) For any given n-square decomposition, having more numbers to choose from for each set means it is more likely to find a set partition fitting the given sums.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the following solutions:

> ```
> n=6:
> 9 = 9
> 16 = 1 + 15
> 25 = 2 + 3 + 7 + 13
> 36 = 5 + 12 + 19
> 64 = 6 + 10 + 14 + 16 + 18
> 81 = 4 + 8 + 11 + 17 + 20 + 21
>
> n=7:
> 4 = 4
> 9 = 1 + 8
> 36 = 7 + 11 + 18
> 49 = 5 + 9 + 10 + 25
> 64 = 3 + 13 + 14 + 15 + 19
> 100 = 2 + 6 + 16 + 21 + 27 + 28
> 144 = 12 + 17 + 20 + 22 + 23 + 24 + 26
>
> n=8:
> 1 = 1
> 25 = 10 + 15
> 49 = 6 + 20 + 23
> 64 = 4 + 7 + 12 + 13 + 28
> 81 = 3 + 16 + 30 + 32
> 100 = 5 + 9 + 11 + 14 + 17 + 18 + 26
> 121 = 2 + 8 + 19 + 24 + 33 + 35
> 225 = 21 + 22 + 25 + 27 + 29 + 31 + 34 + 36
>
> n=9:
> 9 = 9
> 25 = 5 + 7 + 13
> 49 = 6 + 43
> 81 = 3 + 19 + 24 + 35
> 100 = 1 + 10 + 16 + 33 + 40
> 121 = 2 + 4 + 14 + 15 + 21 + 26 + 39
> 169 = 12 + 23 + 25 + 30 + 37 + 42
> 225 = 11 + 17 + 27 + 28 + 29 + 32 + 36 + 45
> 256 = 8 + 18 + 20 + 22 + 31 + 34 + 38 + 41 + 44
>
> n=10:
> 36 = 36
> 49 = 4 + 8 + 15 + 22
> 64 = 19 + 45
> 100 = 21 + 31 + 48
> 121 = 7 + 12 + 16 + 32 + 54
> 169 = 3 + 5 + 10 + 33 + 34 + 37 + 47
> 196 = 11 + 14 + 27 + 39 + 52 + 53
> 225 = 1 + 17 + 18 + 20 + 24 + 29 + 35 + 38 + 43
> 256 = 9 + 13 + 23 + 25 + 40 + 46 + 49 + 51
> 324 = 2 + 6 + 26 + 28 + 30 + 41 + 42 + 44 + 50 + 55
> ```

> I have found solutions for higher $n$ (up to 15), they just take more time. I agree with Bubbler - solutions should exist for all $n \geq 5$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: This is insanely interesting, makes me think about how can you prove that there is a solution existing for all $n \geq 5$?